# How to have to different docker container of same service?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I have 1 Node service.

I Want to run two different instance of the same service on two different container.

I am doing this using below docker commands,

```
docker run -p 9003:9003 --network ${NETWORK} --name database-service --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
docker run -p 9113:9113 --network ${NETWORK} --name database-service-poc --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

When I do this, my first docker container run fine

but the second container somehow takes 9003 only though I am passing 9113 please see below screen shot :

[image]

FYI,

In Node service I am using below code for getting dynamic ports i.e the port which are passed using above docker commands

```
app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  logging.info("Application is running on port: %d in %s mode", app.get('port'), app.get('env'));
  logging.info("process.env.PORT ",process.env.PORT); //In both the docker container it prints 9003
});
```

Comment: you might be interested in kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Check docker swarm https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/.
With swarm you can run a service with parameter `--replicas 2`. You service will create two containers and will manage ports and others access

Comment: This does not resolved my problem. I want to run two different container on two different port and then perform load balance on them

Comment: You wrote you want two instances of the same **service**. service is a "feature" of swarm. Running containers by `docker run` you doesn't create `service`. If both containers are actually the same then you can run swarm, create service for them with `docker service create` and docker will do the load balancing for you - just like @Kilian wrote.

Comment: @Izydorr : I wanted to use the Ribbon for Load Balancer. .  We have Spring-Boot Api-Gateway in Place which forward the request to any of these container.. Now as I mention in my question both the container are using 9003 port instead on one using 9003 and other 9113 I am facing the problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like port forwarding works just fine bu in your image you expose only port 9003. I don't know anything about the stuff you're serving but you should either have both `EXPOSE 9003` and `EXPOSE 9113` in your Dockerfile if your service really listens on both these ports or do the port forwarding like this:

```
docker run -p 9003:9003 --network ${NETWORK} --name database-service --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
docker run -p 9113:9003 --network ${NETWORK} --name database-service-poc --restart always -m 1024M --memory-swap -1 -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

if it's the same service on the same port in both containers and you just want to have different ports for load ballancing.